# how to move two or multiple imageviews together?

Tags: android, android-layout

**i want to move two or multiple imageviews on single touch**

**Detailed Explanation**

> i have two or more imageview in a linearlayout now i want to move imageviews which are inside linearlayout .
>   and when one imageview touches another imageview so both goes underlays each other
>   i want mirrior effect like this app has [see this app to get what i want](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.lyrebirdstudio.mirror&hl=en)

Answer (score 0):

Try these

A simple yet flexible library

https://github.com/clkasd/CarouselViewProject

https://github.com/sayyam/carouselview

Comment: no these links has view pager u see my link then suggest or answer